# Update Checkout Layout and JS behavior in Cornerstone (BigCommerce)

Tags: e-commerce, bigcommerce

When we add the products into `Cart` and proceed to `Checkout` page we can apply the coupon like this.

[image]

It shows unnecessary error in the console.

I checked the `template/pages/checkout.html` but it has this code.

```
{{{ checkout.checkout_content }}}
```

How can I update the `{{{ checkout.checkout_content }}}`  and where is it?
and I also can't find the proper JS code in `assets/js`.
What I guess is this HTML section/js code is dynamically loaded from Bigcommerce API but I can't verify it.

How can I solve my issue?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running on localhost instead of 127.0.0.1, to see if makes any difference?

This is a good situation to get a HAR file, as that would show your network tab details. If you have one, it may be best (and more secure) to [reach out to technical support team](https://support.bigcommerce.com/s/#contact) to review it with you rather than sharing it in StackOverflow. Also, in regards to your question about { checkout.checkout_content } -to modify this, you will need to take a look at [the checkout-js repo](https://github.com/bigcommerce/checkout-js) as it's not available via the theme.

Comment: I will check checkout-js repo and other details.